# Spanned vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that $span\{v_1,v_2\}$ is the set of all linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$. But does it have a difference from $span\{λv_1+μv_2\}$, which is the set of all linear combinations of $λv_1+μv_2$ ?

Comment: The two spans span subspaces of different dimension.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern You mean the first one has dimension two and the second has one?

Comment: $\mathrm{span}\left\{v_1,v_2\right\}$ is the span of a two dimensional space; $\mathrm{span}\left\{\lambda{v}_1+\mu{v}_2\right\}$ is the span of a one dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting $W = \text{span}(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2)$ ($\color{red}{\text{ where the scalars $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are fixed}}$) and $V = \text{span}(v_1, v_2)$, we have that $W \subseteq V$. Indeed, suppose we take an element out of $W$, then it is of the form 
$$a (\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2) = (a \lambda) v_1 + (a \mu) v_2 \in V$$
for some $a \in \mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field over which you consider your vector space (in the case of real vector spaces, $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$.

Now the answer on your question depends on the answer to the following question: "are the vectors $v_1, v_2$ linearly independent?".

In the case the answer is 'yes', we have that $V$ is a $2$-dimensional vectorspace, whereas $W$ is only $1$-dimensional, so we have that $W$ is strictly contained in $V$.

If the answer is 'no' this can have two causes:
1) $v_1$ is nonzero and $v_2$ is a scalar multiple of $v_1$. In this case both $V$ and $W$ are $1$-dimensional and hence $V = W$.
2) both $v_1$ and $v_2$ are zerovectors, in which case both $V$ and $W$ are $0$-dimensional and hence also the same.

Comment: But why is $W$ only $1$-dimensional? Can't I write $W=span\{λv_1,μv_2\}$?

Comment: Isn't $\{λv_1+μv_2:λ,μ \in \Bbb F\}=span\{λv_1+μv_2\}$?

Comment: @Michael $W$ is $1$-dimensional since it is generated by the (single) vector $\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2$. You can not write the second equation, since for example, $\lambda v_1$ is an element of $\text{span}(\lambda v_1, \mu v_2)$, but you can never write this as a multiple of $(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2)$, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ being fixed. (I have edited this in my answer)

Comment: I understand this. But the notation $span\{λv_1+μv_2\}$ means that $λ,μ$ are fixed, where as the notation $\{λv_1+μv_2:λ,μ \in \Bbb F\}$ means that $λ,μ$ go through the whole space $\Bbb F$?

Comment: @Michael: Correct! in $\text{span}(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2)$ we are only allowed to take scalar multiples of the single vector $(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2)$, whereas in $\text{span}(v_1, v_2)$ we can take multiples of $v_1$ and multiples of $v_2$ and then add them (this second span is the one where you said that $\lambda, \mu$ go through the whole space).

Comment: Many thanks! I think this clears out a lot

Comment: @Michael you're welcome :)